# Counting keys in a hash_multimap

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

What is the most efficient way to count all the different keys in a `hash_multimap`?

E.g. if I have a already filled `hash_multimap`, (e.g. a container where you can store multiple entities with a same key)
how can i retrieve the set of keys?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the keys into a `std::set` and find the size of the set.

Comment: Or a `hash_set`, given that for some reason a hash has previously been preferred to a tree for this data.